# Download text file in html with dynamic text

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

I'm trying to create a link on a web page that upon clicking should download/open a text file on the client with the content I have rendered run-time. Saving the file on the server side is not an option since the contents of the file changes based on user's filters that I have as a functionality on the web page.

On my page.cshtml, I have the following:

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'Home/GetTable',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#tab1").append(data.toString());
            },
            error: function (data, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

The controller constructs the HTML code and passes it back to the view. My controller code is as follows:

```
public string GetTable()
        {
            string result = @" <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>                
            <td>Data1</td>
            <td>Data2</td>
            <td><a download href=""file.txt"">Click me</a></td>
        </tr>";    
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;filename=targetFileName.txt");
            return result;
        }
```

I cannot keep creating file[X].txt on the server since the contents of it changes every time based on user's filters that I have else where as logic in my code. Also, where do I feed in my data as contents of the file if I don't have a file in the first place?

What's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to dynamically generate some sort of text file and give it away to a user.
Last time I tried something like that, I used PHP function to generate that file, then set `document.location.href` to that file and had a scheduled task to clear those files once a day.

Comment: I don't want to create a text file on server at all. I'm looking for workarounds which does not involve any server side file creation.